# How to optimize Tomcat for Feed pull

Tags: java, tomcat, akka

We have a mobile app which presents feed to users. The feed REST API is implemented on tomcat, which parallel makes calls to different data sources such as Couchbase, MYSQL to present the content. The simple code is given below:

```
Future<List<CardDTO>> pnrFuture = null;
Future<List<CardDTO>> newsFuture = null;

ExecutionContext ec = ExecutionContexts.fromExecutorService(executor);

final List<CardDTO> combinedDTOs = new ArrayList<CardDTO>();

// Array list of futures 
List<Future<List<CardDTO>>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<List<CardDTO>>>();

futures.add(future(new PNRFuture(pnrService, userId), ec)); 
futures.add(future(new NewsFuture(newsService, userId), ec)); 
futures.add(future(new SettingsFuture(userPreferenceManager, userId), ec)); 

Future<Iterable<List<CardDTO>>> futuresSequence = sequence(futures, ec); 

// combine the cards 
Future<List<CardDTO>> futureSum =  futuresSequence.map( 
        new Mapper<Iterable<List<CardDTO>>, List<CardDTO>>() {
            @Override 
            public List<CardDTO> apply(Iterable<List<CardDTO>> allDTOs) { 
                for (List<CardDTO> cardDTOs : allDTOs) {
                    if (cardDTOs != null) {
                        combinedDTOs.addAll(cardDTOs);
                    } 
                } 

                Collections.sort(combinedDTOs);
                return combinedDTOs;
            } 
        } 
); 

Await.result(futureSum, Duration.Inf());  
return combinedDTOs;
```

Right now we have around 4-5 parallel tasks per request. But it is expected to grow to almost 20-25 parallel tasks as we introduce new kinds of items in feed.

My question is, how can I improve this design? What kind of tuning is required in Tomcat to make sure such 20-25 parallel calls can be served optimally under heavy load.

I understand this is a broad topic, but any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: is there a requirement to return all data in a single request?

Comment: Yes, the complete feed is returned. In future, it may be paginated...

Comment: @madhur-ahuja: There are plenty of things that can be improved to make a design like this better - It seems to me that you're trying to implement something like [http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html] (microservices) to aggregate different sources of data to a feed.

Problem is... tomcat is the least of your problems. Since every remote service can fail, you'll need focus on system resiliency to actually pull off a design like this.

Circuit breakers and balancers are the first thing that come to my mind, but they're off-scope of the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you are calling this from a mobile app and the number of feeds could go up.

based on the amount of data being returned, would it be possible to return the results of some feeds in the same call?
That way the server does the work.
You are in control of the server - you are not in control of the users device and their connection speed.

As nickebbit suggested, things like DefferedResult are really easy to implement. 
is it possible that the data from these feeds would not be updated in a quick fashion? If so - you should investigate the use of EHCache and the @Cacheable annotation.

You could come up with a solution where the user is always pulling a cached version of your content from your tomcat server. But your tomcat server is constantly updating that cache in the background.

Its an extra piece of work - but at the end of the day if the user experience is not fast - users will not want to use this app

Answer (score 7):

Tomcat just manages the incoming HTTP connections and pushes the bytes back and forth. There is no Tomcat optimization that can be done to make your application run any better.

If you need 25 parallel processes to run for each incoming HTTP request, and you think that's crazy, then you need to re-think how your application works.

No tomcat configuration will help with what you've presented in your question.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your using Akka but not really embracing the Actor model, doing so will likely increase the parallelism and therefore scalability of your app.

If it was me I'd hand requests off from my REST API to a single or pool of coordinating actors that will process the request asynchronously. Using Spring's RestController this can be done using a `Callable` or `DeferredResult` but there will obviously be an equivalent in whatever framework you are using.

This coordinating actor would then in turn hand off processing to other actors (i.e. workers) that take care of the I/O bound tasks (preferably using their own dispatcher to ensure other CPU bound threads do not get blocked) and respond to the coordinator with their results.

Once all workers have fetched their data and replied to the coordinator with the results then the original request can be completed with the full result set.